# Java Mail API can't delete messages

Tags: java

I have some confusion about message deleting. I have well 
connection to email, but code didn't work.

```
public class GetMyInbox {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Properties prop = System.getProperties();
    prop.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    System.out.println("Start connection...");

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(prop,null);
    try {
        Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
        store.connect("host", "email","password");
        System.out.println("Connected!");

        Folder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

        Message msg = folder.getMessage(1779);
        Address from = msg.getFrom()[0];

        List<Message> messages = Arrays.asList(folder.getMessages());
        for (Message m : messages) {
          if (m.getFrom()[0].equals(from)) {
          m.setFlag(Flags.Flag.DELETED, true);
            }
         }

          } catch ...
```

method equals don't work.
I tried do the same with string

```
if (m.getFrom()[0].toString().contains("string")){
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm confused about which part "didn't work" - the `equals` check, or the `setFlag`, or something else? Did you get an exception, or some other error?

Comment: java programm just thinking long time with no message

Comment: i tried print in console instead delete  and the same. look like method equals is wrong

Comment: Instead of just running it from console and relying on log statements, use a debugger. Stepping through your code in a debugger will let you watch the code flow and examine variables as the program executes, which very often makes the problem very obvious. Please do this and update your question with what you find out while debugging.

Comment: after deep dive in problem, obviously, **I got off easy**. Program work correctly, and confuse was that it iterate my mails during 9 min and many mails from same sender made illusion than iteration didn't work. But debugging show algoritm and I all understood. thanx very much for attention, Krease
i' ll be more reasonable next

Comment: Glad to hear you were able to resolve the issue!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the flag has changed to deleted (it doesn't delete physically). While fetching emails you have to exclude /delete flags.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31860287)